# Trouble implementing jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am having trouble implementing a jquery slider (flexslider)

I feel like I am missing something very basic, but for some reason I just cannot put my finger on it. Any help would be amazing. The link to the test site is below.

I am trying to get the slider to appear in the empty green area.

I am also working in Gumby responsive framework

http://4grain.bmdigitalgroup.com/

Comment: you have a typo in your analytics code.. `<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js"></script>` add `http:` to the beginning of the script.. still searching for the slider bug though.

Comment: @McMastermind the protocol-less link is valid. It used commonly used to solved the problem of not knowing if the page is https or http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your issue:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider'
```

...also looks like your loading your jquery file after the flexslider file.  try keeping all your .js files in one place, with your jquery file on top of all of them.

You have 2 jquery files loaded on the same page. you should only need one, unless you are intentiontally trying to load 2 of them..

try placing your script...

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
```

at the bottom of the page, wrapped in a script tag, before the body ends, instead of inside the head of the page.  the script is waiting until the page is loaded anyway.

UPDATE!

Hey good job so far!  i'm seeing what you have done on your page via the web console.
And if you want to get rid of that...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on'
```

...then remove the jquery 1.6.2 file from the top of your page, and place the fexslider.js file at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Which means you probably have a double reference to the jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

Give `#maincontentbody` a `height`, perhaps `75px`, then all of the children need to have a defined `height` and `width`, even id it's `width:100%`. `min-height` is not an appropriate value in this case

Your images appear to be much larger than the green bar area, do you think it will animate as well?

Comment: I scaled the image to fit the 14 column layout I am working in

Comment: By "all of the children" do you mean the actual img files inside the #maincontentbody?

Comment: Fix the javascript error first. That probably has an effect with how the layout is built.

Comment: Sorry, premature return hit. By children, I mean that when I check out the html in Firebug, div.row, div.fourteen and ul.slides all don't appear to have a height and width. So they appear collapsed.

Comment: All of this input was very helpful and I got it to work!

I changed the height via Jason Lydon and Cody Guldner

Took out the double reference via blachawk and MGDtech

and then switched around the Jquery code and moved the slider launch to the bottom of my code via blachawk!

You guys are awesome!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As noted, you are having a double reference to the jquery library. Try doing this which will stop the dual references:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $.noConflict();
  $(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
</script>
```

Comment: All of this input was very helpful and I got it to work!

I changed the height via Jason Lydon and Cody Guldner

Took out the double reference via blachawk and MGDtech

and then switched around the Jquery code and moved the slider launch to the bottom of my code via blachawk!

You guys are awesome!!!!